# Работа с файлом, полученным из input "file"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Стоит задача из .docx документа импортировать текст в md. Есть ли возможность реализовать все это ***(получение файла)*** в клиентской части?

Comment: Это задача, если нет готового решения в сети, может занять не одну неделю разработки.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, у меня это реализовано на php с использованием библиотек. Там у меня возникает сложность с передачей пути до файла методом ajax. 

Было желание реализовать это на клиентской части, без создания ajax-запросов.

Comment: Ну вот на php вы использовали библиотеки. Если найдете их аналоги на js - можете попробовать решить на js. Но по мне - легче разобраться с AJAX и путями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, получение файла на клиентской части (и обработка его содержимого) вполне возможна.

Пример ([поддерживается большинством браузеров, в том числе мобильных](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)):

```js
function onFileLoad(elementId, event) {
  document.getElementById(elementId).innerText = event.target.result;
}

function onChooseFile(event, onLoadFileHandler) {
  if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function')
    throw ("The file API isn't supported on this browser.");
  let input = event.target;
  if (!input)
    throw ("The browser does not properly implement the event object");
  if (!input.files)
    throw ("This browser does not support the `files` property of the file input.");
  if (!input.files[0])
    return undefined;
  let file = input.files[0];
  let fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = onLoadFileHandler;
  fr.readAsText(file);
}
```

```html
<input type='file' onchange='onChooseFile(event, onFileLoad.bind(this, "contents"))' />
<br>
<div style="background: #e9e9e9">
  <code id="contents"></code>
</div>
```

Далее вам придётся обрабатывать контент файла (парсинг docx и т.п.), а это уже другая задача.

Comment: А что если использовать временный путь до файла?

Comment: @ТигранАрустамов если файл лежит на диске и браузер поддерживается, то файл должен быть считан.

Comment: Попробую использовать временный путь - напишу, что получилось

Comment: @ТигранАрустамов что вы подразумеваете под "временным путём"?

Comment: Что то по типу такого: blob:http://fiddle.jshell.net/2f386172-702f-47b5-b4eb-4a70c2f7bace

Comment: @ТигранАрустамов сомневаюсь, да и в вопросе формулировка указана немного не так — а на вопрос в текущей формулировке я полностью ответил.

Comment: Т.е. на событие onchange выполнять код, который будет отслеживать файл

Comment: Да, я сейчас рассматриваю сразу несколько вариантов решений. Буду тестировать